# Bind readonly variable to variable inside class C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to write myself a little utility library for creating graphics on windows forms. In this, I would like to create a class by the name of "Menu".

I would like Menu to contain a value called "Count" which holds the number of entries in the menu, which I would like to be read only and mirror the value of another value called "Contents.Count". While I could just type Contents.Count, I would still like to find out how to do this and whether it's recommended to do this or if there's a better way of doing it.

I have tried using get and set, but apart from that I am completely stumped in how to take this on. I know how to create a basic read only variable, and how to set its initial value with the constructor, yet not how to mirror a value with it.

My current, non functional attempt:

```
readonly int Count;
static List<Delegate> Contents 
{ 
  get { return Contents; }
  set 
  {
    Contents = value;
    Count = Contents.Count;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# 6.0 syntax:

```
Int32 Count => Contents.Count;
```

In C# 5.0 and older syntax:

```
Int32 Count
{
    get { return Contents.Count; }
}
```